# C# Multithreading .abort() .suspend() .reusme()

Tags: c#

how to Abort, pause or resume a thread?

cause im having run time error with .`Abort()`(Object reference was not set to an object instance.) and with `.Resume()` and `.Suspend()` there is a Obselete error.

I tryed in my `Run()` a Thread.Sleep(1000) But i realize that it will not work because it's not the instance of the thread that was used.

Any idea how can i do it?

thx

CODE:

```
class FolderStats : IFolderStats
{
    Thread MyThread = null;
    private bool x;
    string Rootpath;
    List<string> MyList = new List<string>();
    Folder FD = new Folder();

    public void Connect(string rootpath)
    {

        Console.WriteLine(Statuses.Waiting);
        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        FD.Path = rootpath;
        Rootpath = rootpath;

        Console.WriteLine(Statuses.Connected);
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        MyThread = new Thread(Run);
        MyThread.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("Starting the Search");
    }          
    public void Stop()
    {
        MyThread.Abort();
        Console.WriteLine("Console Aborted. Please press Enter to Exit");
    }
    public void Pause()
    {
        this.x = false;
        PauseResume();
        Console.WriteLine("Console Paused.");
    }
    public void Resume()
    {
        this.x = true;
        PauseResume();
        Console.WriteLine("Console Resumed.");
    }
    private void PauseResume()
    {
        while (this.x == false)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }
    public void Run()
    {

        MyThread = new Thread(Start);
        if (!MyList.Contains(Rootpath))
        {
            MyList.Add(Rootpath);
            var subDirs = Directory.GetDirectories(Rootpath, "*");
            var Data = Directory.GetFiles(Rootpath, "*");

            foreach (string dir in subDirs)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
                Rootpath = dir;
                Console.WriteLine(dir);

                Run();
            }
            foreach (string file in Data)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
                if (!MyList.Contains(file))
                {
                    MyList.Add(file);
                    Console.WriteLine(file);
                }
            }
        }
        FD.NumberOfFiles = MyList.Count; 
    }
```

Comment: Do not abort, pause or resume threads. What is particular task you are trying to solve?

Comment: Data collection should be done in the background after calling Start(). It can be stopped or paused and resumed at any time.

Comment: see also http://www.albahari.com/threading/

Comment: If one thread has sufficient information to actually know that it is safe to abort or suspend another thread, there *must* be some form of interaction happening such that *you can put some other inter-thread mechanism in place* to allow for orderly pausing/shutdown. If you *don't* have that knowledge/communication then these methods are inherently *unsafe*, hence why they're marked Obsolete.

Comment: _some other inter-thread mechanism_ - like Abort => support interruption. Suspend/Resume => use for example Barrier, or Condition, or ManualResetEvent, or  ...

Answer (score 1):

Do not use Thread, use Task instead.
You can run new task:

```
Task.Run(()=>...);
```

You can use CancellationToken/CancellationTokenSource to achieve make your task cancelable:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtokensource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

If you want to pause your task you can try to implement something like this:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2013/01/13/cooperatively-pausing-async-methods/

Comment: Suggesting a whole different concept is not really getting the OP to learn why he shouldn't be using these exact Methods (Pause, Resume, Abort) and what he can do instead (using the same "Threading concept"). So, although TAP should probably be the way to go, I cannot upvote this answer. (But won't down either)